# How to handle an angry mob?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I dared to raise a suggestion that [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/157523/2998) doesn't really answer the question. The question was about installment sales using credit cards, and the answer was lecturing the OP that credit cards are for credit, completely ignoring the component of installment in the question.

In response I got downvoted into oblivion, claimed that I'm "guessing", that the OP doesn't know the meaning of the words they're using, and that the installment sales using credit cards do not exist.

None of it is true of course.

That same person came then here to [accuse me](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/how-do-we-track-recurrent-bigotry-and-eliminate-it) of "bigotry", because I dared to call him out on not knowing that installment sales  do in fact exist, and I even provided examples [in my answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/157520/2998).

I know I can't expect people to learn new things if they don't want to. But how can I ask them to stop shitposting their stupidity under my answer? How can I block them from commenting?

Comment: Doubling down by stating "Especially not Americans, people known for their ignorance, arrogance, and inability to learn across the whole world." isn't helping your case and distracts from whatever valid points you may have...

Comment: I didn't follow the original discussion but I note that you're talking about American *people* here, not infrastructure. Be it online or IRL, it would behoove you to refrain from making sweeping statements about entire populations, as your personal experience and biases may not be representative and you end up revealing more about yourself than the people you criticize. I don't know where you're from (nor do I care) but if somebody painted all the members of whatever group you identify with with the same brush you might get touchy too... In any case, it doesn't add to your argument.

Comment: I don't have an axe to grind, just remember there are over 330 million Americans and they aren't all the same. Two wrongs don't make a right and if you continue like this, at least you shouldn't act surprised when people perceive you as being confrontational or bigoted...

Comment: On the topic of proving points... Bigoted (MWD): "having or showing an attitude of hatred or intolerance toward the members of a particular group (such as a racial or ethnic group)" You may very well think they're assholes, the fact (or assumption) that they're American is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can flag any comment or answer that is inappropriate and let the mods handle it.

Also, you have a history of being fairly confrontational with multiple people on this site. Maybe take a more constructive tone to avoid getting in scuffles with other users to avoid this situation.

Comment: Yeah, just flag it and let the mods handle it. Don't feed trolls or engage once it gets nasty